# Why Hibernate provides me only interceptor and I catch JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would be very grateful to you for help.

I use Spring Boot 2.5.2.
DB: H2 with Liquibase

I need to change ticket History when attachment is removed.
This is my entities:

Ticket:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_owner_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Attachment> attachments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<History> history;   

    // other fields and relationships
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Ticket> ownerTickets;

    // other fields and relationships
}
```

Attachment:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String filename;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
    private byte[] file;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", nullable = false)
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

History:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class History {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "changed_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime changedDate;

    private String action;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Services:

JpaAttachmentService:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JpaAttachmentService implements AttachmentService {

    private final AttachmentRepository attachmentRepository;
    private final HistoryService historyService;   

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(Long id, Long ticketId, Long userId) {
        var attachment = attachmentRepository.getByIdAndTicketIdAndTicketOwnerId(id, ticketId, userId);
        var action = "File is removed";
        var description = "File is removed: " + attachment.getFilename();
        var ticket = attachment.getTicket();
        var user = attachment.getUser();

        var history = new History(null, LocalDateTime.now(), action, description, ticket, user);
        historyService.save(history);

        attachmentRepository.deleteByIdAndTicketIdAndTicketOwnerId(id, ticketId, userId);
    }
}
```

When I try to 'historyService.save(history)' I catch:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
update history set action=?, description=?, ticket_id=?, user_id=? where id=? [23502-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:459)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:374)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Update.update(Update.java:176)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 144 more
```

This is 'var user' debug:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLIRd.png)

I can't understand why I get this Hibernate Interceptor but not entity. I confused when I see inside interceptor required UserID and when I see 'null' outside of it. Could you help me with this problem, please?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What method is called when you have this problem? save(Attachment) ?

Comment: No, historyService.save(history);

Comment: @VadimVolkov check the answer below

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sorry for confusing, I made some fixes to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is quite informative regarding the error you are experiencing. Take a look at the following part:

> NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement: update history
> set action=?, description=?, ticket_id=?, user_id=? where id=?

What you attempt to do is to save an instance of a `History` entity which without passing in a reference to a `User` object. Since your relation dictates that the `user` reference cannot be null:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
```

To fix this, either make sure that a non-null reference to a `User` object is passed in when inserting/updating the `History` reference, or modify your database constraint design to allow for null user references at the `History` entity.

Comment: I understand this exception. I can't understand how to get not null User. Attachment shouldn't exist without User that's why I insert "nullable = false". But even in your proposed way, I tried to do it and caught another exception related to "nullable = false". I can't realise why I get Hibernate Interceptor but not User entity.

Comment: What do you mean by ` I can't realise why I get Hibernate Interceptor but not User entity`?

Comment: As can you see in the picture, attachment.getUser() returns me not entity but Hibernate Interceptor. But I know exactly that this entity exists. You can see it in 'target' field in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to test, but in the further development I faced it again. So I want to share my solution.
Maybe it will help you.
Pay attention to CascadeType! Cascading operations must be specified above the link to the child relation. In my case, I have to remove this relation or leave Ticket with CascadeType.PERSIST

Fixed class Attachment:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String filename;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
    private byte[] file;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  // or cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", nullable = false)
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```